# Can I wire a microwave blower fan to a plug by itself?

Tags: electrical

I have a "OH SUNG" Microwave blower fan (6549W1V006c) that I would like to use by itself for something else. Im not sure if the plug I have will work on it but Im posting pictures of the fan wires, along with the plug wires. The blower fan has a black, white, red, yellow and blue wires. The plug has black, white, and green wires. Is this possible or what kind of plug would I need to wire it to? Thanks for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

See the wiring diagram on the fan. It needs a starter capacitor between the red and yellow wires; then power (black and white from the plug) can be applied to black and blue for high speed or white and blue for low speed.

There is no ground wire for the fan -- hopefully it is either in a plastic case or otherwise double-insulated so it doesn't need one -- so the green wire from the plug can be left unconnected.

Comment: If the fan's in a metal box -- simply drill/tap a 10-32 hole in said box, and then attach the ground with a ring terminal on a 10-32 screw + lockwasher

Comment: And if the fan isn't in a metal box, find the biggest piece of metal structure and ground that.

Comment: Heyo, you don't exactly need a starting cap, you can always spin the fan blades and then plug it in whilst it is still spinning.(I know from experience as well)